# How can I run .py file from another directory in jupyter notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I am working on a jupyter notebook file in a folder `project`. I have a `package_code.py` file in another folder called `packages`. How can I run the `package_code.py` file in the jupyter notebook file I am working on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a line magic like this:

```
%run path/to/myfile.py
```

So if `project` and `packages` are in the same folder one level back, you would need:

```
%run ../packages/package_code.py
```

Comment: answer is missing -i, therefore it should be: %run -i path/to/myfile.py